# Java reterofit classes with multiple constructors vs multiple classes

Tags: java, express, retrofit2

I want to use my REST API in combination with a java application.
As I started to design my program, everything was fine, but now I'm facing a big problem:

For example my user class has attributes like id, balance, name.
When I create a new User by sending a POST request, attributes like id and balance are not needed.

This brings me to the question:

- Should I POST a different object (like UserCreate, has only required attributes for creating a new user) to the API and receive a full User object?

OR

- Should I add another constructor to my User object, that does only require all required parameters (name)?

I believe that in this situation, an additional constructor might be considered as good practice, but what if **posting would require a set of completely different attributes? (attributes that are not included in my user class)**?

(Another approach would be to work with Object(), but somehow that didn't work (Express says, its a http 400). Is it even possible in retrofit2 to send anon Objects in a Post request?)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your Java application should take account all the needed operations like CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE. These are - roughly - identified with HTTP methods `PUT`, `PATCH` &  `DELETE` correspondingly.

Now, the DTO representationyour frontend sends (JSON/XML/REST) to Java backend can be the same in each case: CREATE, UPDATE & DELETE. Your backend should implement above mentioned functionality for HTTP methods listed above. The **DTO** (maybe named UserDTO) you send from frontend to backend can be the same in all cases. In this DTO you can just leave all the unrelated (unrelated to the operation) fields unset/null.

More detailed: your backend should have methods accepting HTTP methods:

- `PUT` where DTO has all other needed fields but **Id**
- `PATCH` where DTO has **Id** field and all the **changed** fields
- `DELETE` where DTO has only the **Id**

I do not know about how the frameworks you use constructs the actual POJO from the DTO you send. But now you have those three methods in which you actually know how to handle the incoming DTO i.e. you know if it is CREATE,UPDATE or DELETE.

So if you need to construct POJOs by yourself you need constructor for CREATE, for update it is hard to say, maybe you need to fetch the original user and update it field by field and for delete actually the id should be sufficient to delete the User.

> but what if posting would require a set of completely different attributes? (attributes that are not included in my user class)?

That seems to be a HTTP `POST`. So it is not CREATE, UPDATE or DELETE operation but something that changes the state - perhaps the User - based on some arbitrary operation and data. Of course for data not in the User you need some other DTO to hold this data.